# Maven: How do I download/include a file from a remote repository?

Tags: maven-2, maven, selenium

I"m using Maven 3.0.3.  For our projects, we spin up a Selenium server for our integration-test phases in order to run tests.  We have a custom user-extensions file that we integrate like below ...

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <background>true</background>
                                <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                                <userExtensions>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium/user-extensions.js</userExtensions>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

This file exists in a git repository and I would prefer we download the latest version of the file from the git repository rather than copying it into our project and manually updating all projects when a new version of the file comes out.  However, I don't know how to get the latest version of the file and include it in the plugin in Maven.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

use the maven-scm-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Foo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>export</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <connectionUrl>scm:git:...</connectionUrl>
                        <exportDirectory>${project.build.directory}</exportDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Bare in mind that, with this approach, if you have other files/directories under this folder (`${connectionUrl}`), that those files will also be checked out. Therefore, I suggest you consider Torsten's solution.

Comment: But the connectionUrl can pick out an individual file.

Comment: Interesting. Some time ago I had tried this (for one reason or the other). At the time I was using Subversion? Does git support single file checkouts?

Comment: Well, in this case, I am fairly sure, this won't allow you checkout/export a single file, but rather -- an entire directory.

Answer (score 2):

The maven way to solve this is to build a separate module containing this file in the resulting artifact (e.g. a jar or zip file) and deploy it to your maven repository.

You may then use the maven dependencies plugin to retrieve it from the maven repository, unpack it to you target folder and reference it in your selenium plugin call.

Comment: How does this solve the original requirement? _"I would prefer we download the latest version of the file from the git repository rather than copying it into our project and manually updating all projects when a new version of the file comes out."_

Comment: Normally with Maven around, there is also a CI server (Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity), which take care of re-deploying the SNAPSHOT-s to the Maven repository. Extracting such resources to a separate module makes sense to me and a lot of other people who are doing things this way.

Comment: It depends on if you really always want to retrieve the latest version or if you opt for reproducibility of your build. Using the repository allows you to specify the version of the artifact you are using, while using the scm plugin will always give you the latest version. If this is what you want you should probably use scm-aproach shown in the other entry.

Comment: Hi Torsten, Thanks but is there any other way to check out a single file from a git repository (I always want the latest version) and copy it into my build?  Building a new module for just a single Javascript file seems like overkill.